Storing Binary String in DynamoDb
I am trying to store a binary string in DynamoDB using Java.  However, the builder is converting the bytes somehow.  My original string is a zipped string.  If I pass:
H4sIAAAAAAAAA7LJKMnNsePlsslITUyxsynJLMlJtTMxMFXwyy9RcMzJyS9PTbHRhwjb6IMVARUn5adUKiSlJ+fn5BfZKpVnZJakKoHEk1PzSlKL7GwyDDHNAIrZ6EMVgOwDKoPy8tIz8yr0DfUMDfVMkZXog6wBM6COBAAAAP//AwBuTqCXrQAAAA==
The value in the database is converted to:
SDRzSUFBQUFBQUFBQTdMSktNbk5zZVBsc3NsSVRVeXhzeW5KTE1sSnRUTXhNRlh3eXk5UmNNekp5UzlQVGJIUmh3amI2SU1WQVJVbjVhZFVLaVNsSitmbjVCZlpLcFZuWkpha0tvSEVrMVB6U2xLTDdHd3lEREhOQUlyWjZFTVZnT3dES29QeTh0SXo4eXIwRGZVTURmVk1rWlhvZzZ3Qk02Q09CQUFBQVAvL0F3QnVUcUNYclFBQUFBPT0=
Object responseMap = mMap.get("Response");
LinkedHashMap<String, String> responseMapped = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>)responseMap;

String status = statusMapped.get("N");
String response = responseMapped.get("B");

SdkBytes bytes = SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(response);

historyValueMap.put("Status", AttributeValue.builder().n(status).build());
historyValueMap.put("Response", AttributeValue.builder().b(bytes).build());

historyMap.put(historyKey, AttributeValue.builder().m(historyValueMap).build());

I also tried to convert the byte array to a base64 but that didn't work either.
String status = statusMapped.get("N");
byte[] response = responseMapped.get("B").getBytes();

byte[] base64Response = Base64.getEncoder().encode(response);
SdkBytes responseAsSdk = SdkBytes.fromByteArray(base64Response);

historyValueMap.put("Status", AttributeValue.builder().n(status).build());
historyValueMap.put("Response", AttributeValue.builder().b(responseAsSdk).build());


Here is a really simple example from our documentation:
    public static void createItem(String threadId, String replyDateTime) throws IOException {

        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);

        // Craft a long message
        String messageInput = "Long message to be compressed in a lengthy forum reply";

        // Compress the long message
        ByteBuffer compressedMessage = compressString(messageInput.toString());

        table.putItem(new Item().withPrimaryKey("Id", threadId).withString("ReplyDateTime", replyDateTime)
                .withString("Message", "Long message follows").withBinary("ExtendedMessage", compressedMessage)
                .withString("PostedBy", "User A"));
    }

    public static void retrieveItem(String threadId, String replyDateTime) throws IOException {

        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);

        GetItemSpec spec = new GetItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("Id", threadId, "ReplyDateTime", replyDateTime)
                .withConsistentRead(true);

        Item item = table.getItem(spec);

        // Uncompress the reply message and print
        String uncompressed = uncompressString(ByteBuffer.wrap(item.getBinary("ExtendedMessage")));

        System.out.println("Reply message:\n" + " Id: " + item.getString("Id") + "\n" + " ReplyDateTime: "
                + item.getString("ReplyDateTime") + "\n" + " PostedBy: " + item.getString("PostedBy") + "\n"
                + " Message: "
                + item.getString("Message") + "\n" + " ExtendedMessage (uncompressed): " + uncompressed + "\n");
    }



    private static ByteBuffer compressString(String input) throws IOException {
        // Compress the UTF-8 encoded String into a byte[]
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream os = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
        os.write(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.close();
        baos.close();
        byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();

        // The following code writes the compressed bytes to a ByteBuffer.
        // A simpler way to do this is by simply calling
        // ByteBuffer.wrap(compressedBytes);
        // However, the longer form below shows the importance of resetting the
        // position of the buffer
        // back to the beginning of the buffer if you are writing bytes directly
        // to it, since the SDK
        // will consider only the bytes after the current position when sending
        // data to DynamoDB.
        // Using the "wrap" method automatically resets the position to zero.
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(compressedBytes.length);
        buffer.put(compressedBytes, 0, compressedBytes.length);
        buffer.position(0); // Important: reset the position of the ByteBuffer
                            // to the beginning
        return buffer;
    }

    private static String uncompressString(ByteBuffer input) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = input.array();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPInputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(bais);

        int chunkSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer, 0, chunkSize)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        String result = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");

        is.close();
        baos.close();
        bais.close();

        return result;
    }


Unfortunately, this example doesn't help me much unless I change the manner in which I'm updating DynamoDB.  I'm using a PutItemRequest which requires I do something like this:
codehistoryValueMap.put("Response", AttributeValue.builder().b(bytes).build());
